# API Create Category With "Use All Available Attributes" Selected

Tags: magento-1.9, category, api, soap-api-v2, category-attribute

I'm trying to create my categories as follows

For `Available Product Listing Sort By` I want the `Use All Available Attributes` checkbox to be checked

For `Default Product Listing Sort By` I want the `Use Config Settings` to be checked.

So I want it to be like this. (It's in dutch my apologies)
[image]

I already tried to create it like this

```
"available_sort_by"=new string[] {"false"}
"default_sort_by"="false"
```

I read somewhere that that should fix it but it didn't
I also tried to leave it empty like this but that didn't work either
    "available_sort_by"=new string[] {""}
    "default_sort_by"=""

I hope someone can help me out on how to fix this.
Because it's really a pain in the ass when you import 70+ categories and you need to check those boxes for every single one...

Answer (score 0):

You probably figured this out by now, but for anyone else looking, I used it like this:

```
"available_sort_by" => array()
```

and it worked just fine for Magento 1.9